# .click() not working in iframe in ie

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe

My project is an `asp.net` project and i have a separate page named "Districting", and it's called from an `iframe`.
In Districting.aspx page, there is a function that fires a .click() event for a button:

The button clicked by the user:

```
<button id="b1" onclick="DoneClicked();">Done</button>
```

The function is:

```
function DoneClicked(){
    $("#button1").click();
}
```

button1 is the id of an asp button, which calls a function from the server side:

```
<asp:Button id="button1" cssClass="invisiblebutton" OnClick="AddingDistrict" runat="server" />
```

The cssClass, invisiblebutton contains the property: `display:none`.

The problem is that `$("#button1").click()` event is not working only in IE, so it's not calling the function `AddingDistrict()` from cs page.
It is working fine in chrome and FireFox.
Can anyone help me about this issue?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps javascript in ie is disabled
check it